# GDB Support STL visualisation (pretty printing)

Tags: c++, python, stl, gdb

GDB 7.0 added pretty prnting for STL object. However this implementation supports only GCC version of STL. If you are using Dinkum STL implementation for example, you probably see this message:

```
  File "c:/development/bbndk/python\libstdcxx\v6\printers.py", line 588, in to_string
    ptr = self.val ['_M_dataplus']['_M_p']
gdb.error: There is no member or method named _M_dataplus.
```

Does anybody knows about  open source or commertial implementation of pretty printer library compatible with Dinkum?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen you before. Do you create a new user account every time you come here to ask a question? :)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying libstdcxx/v6/printers.py to work with Dinkum STL ought to be pretty trivial.

> Does anybody knows about open source or commertial implementation of pretty printer library compatible with Dinkum

Ask Dinkum?

Comment: I don't understand all the down votes. Are you guys asserting that it is *not* trivial to adjust libstdcxx printers for Dinkum? Or that doing so would not help the OP?